# How to access values of child node from angularfire2 list?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I have an angularfire2 list which is used to display a list of posts. Each post includes a child node (favourites) containing the id's of the users that mark it as a favourite.

What I would like to be able to do is compare the favourites against the current user ID to determine if the add to favourites button is shown.

My question is, how can I access the values from the child node favourites to check if it contains the current user so i can for instance use *ngIf to hide the button?

example template:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of posts | async">
    <img src="{{ item.img }}" />
    <ion-card-content>
        <button ion-button (click)="postsProvider.addFavourite(item.$key)">add to favourites</button>
        <p>
            {{ item.reason }}
        </p>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

example structure:

```
"reasons" : {
    "-KsjNGF9MOj9PYVtcP0F" : {
      "favourites" : {
        "wYWVy8eR85btVhLw7ra9eLSce632" : true,
        "l6ivMgzNE9ZUmHQRwySoaMgiW0J3" : true
      },
      "img" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com",
      "reason" : "asadafaf",
      "userId" : "wYWVy8eR85btVhLw7ra9eLSce632"
    },
    "-KsjWsxJT14IZT-u-mSZ" : {
      "dateCreated" : "Tue Aug 29 2017 18:38:02 GMT+0000 (GMT)",
      "favourites" : {
        "l6ivMgzNE9ZUmHQRwySoaMgiW0J3" : true
      },
      "img" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/",
      "reason" : "asdasdasda",
      "userId" : "wYWVy8eR85btVhLw7ra9eLSce632"
    },
  }
```

I have been working on other parts of the app, namely the page to display user favourites and I discovered something that seems very odd to me.

the favourites page uses the following function to get the favourited items

```
  getUserFavourites() {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return this.db.list('/reasons/', {
      query: {
          orderByChild: 'favourites/' + user + '/favourited',
          equalTo: true
      }
    });
  }
```

I then display the information like this:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let item of posts | async" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
        <div class="card-img" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + item.img + ')'"></div>

        <div class="remove-favourite" (click)="postsProvider.removeFavourite(item.$key)">
            <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
                {{ item.reason }}

            </ion-card-title>
            <p>
                {{ item.favourites[userId].note }}
            </p>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Using this method I am able to use {{ item.favourites[userId].note }} and the value is returned. However, with a nearly identical setup apart from a slightly different query (below) the same does not work.

```
getPosts(limit) {
    return this.db.list('/reasons', {
      query: {
          limitToFirst: limit
      }
    });
 }
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I don't see why there would be differences between the results apart from they use slightly different queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what was causing the problem.

When I used *ngIf="post.favourites[userId].favourited !== true" or tried to display the value then if a post did not have any favourites then it would show an error.

To fix this I added a check to make sure that post.favourites was set by adding an or statement

```
*ngIf="!post.favourites || post.favourites[userId].favourited !== true"
```